# How to display value of map which is also a map in <g:select> or <select> tag?

Tags: html, grails, groovy, gsp

I have a map which is like this :

```
final static def BANK_NAMES = [
        bofa:[fullname:'Bank of America',hasPin:false],
        chase:[fullname:'Chase Bank',hasPin:false],
        wells:[fullname:'Wells Fargo Bank',hasPin:false],
        citi:[fullname:'Citibank',hasPin:false],
        us:[fullname:'US Bank',hasPin:false],
        usaa:[fullname:'USAA',hasPin:false],
        charles:[fullname:'Charles Schwab',hasPin:false]
]
```

I tried to display value in  like this :

```
<g:each in="${BankConstants.BANK_NAMES}" var="banks">
<option id="status">${banks}</option>
</g:each>
```

and it shows like this :

```
bofa={fullname=Bank of America, hasPin=false}
```

Is there a way to show value of "fullname" in a  or  tag. Can anyone please help??

Comment: `<option id="status">${banks.value.fullname}</option>`

Comment: ideally `id` should be unique within a document

Comment: @KamilMikolajczyk yeah  that works  when we loop it thanks!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
<g:each in="${BankConstants.BANK_NAMES}" var="banks">
    <option id="status">${banks.value.fullname}</option>
</g:each>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change

```
final static def BANK_NAMES = [
    [id: 'bofa', fullname:'Bank of America',hasPin:false],
    [id: 'chase', fullname:'Chase Bank',hasPin:false],
    [id: 'wells', fullname:'Wells Fargo Bank',hasPin:false],
    [id: 'citi', fullname:'Citibank',hasPin:false],
    [id: 'us', fullname:'US Bank',hasPin:false],
    [id: 'usaa', fullname:'USAA',hasPin:false],
    [id: 'charles', fullname:'Charles Schwab',hasPin:false]
]
```

so you wil have List of Maps. Then you have acces to fullname by:

```
${banks.fullname}
```

**Edit:**
You can also try:

```
<g:each in="${BankConstants.BANK_NAMES.value}" var="banks">
    <option id="status">${banks.fullname}</option>
</g:each>
```

but I'm not sure if this will work.

Comment: `.value` should work as it implies `*.value`.  or use `.values()` for less groovy.